Adding number line on scanned PDFs
I am still looking for a solution: anybody out there willing to assist. This is a scanned PDF that I want to add some number lines and I have tried pytesseract, reportlab but am not getting the needed outcome.

What I am looking for is below

What am currently getting

Here is my updated code, Its working but not accurate
    import sys
    from collections import defaultdict
    from io import BytesIO
    from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter
    from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
    from pdf2image import convert_from_path
    import pytesseract
    from PIL import Image

    # Set the path to Tesseract executable (Windows-specific, adjust as needed)
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program 
    Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

    # Define path to Poppler on Windows
    poppler_path = r'C:\Program Files\poppler-24.07.0\Library\bin'


    def extract_text_and_positions_from_image(image):
     """Use Tesseract to extract text and their positions from an image."""
        data = pytesseract.image_to_data(image, 
    output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT)
        return data


    def add_line_numbers_to_scanned_pdf(pdf_file_path, 
    output_pdf_path):
      """Add line numbers to a scanned PDF using OCR."""
        images = convert_from_path(pdf_file_path, 300, 
    poppler_path=poppler_path)  # Convert the scanned PDF to images

        pdf_writer = PdfWriter()  # Writer to create a new PDF with 
    line numbers

for page_num, image in enumerate(images):
    # Extract text and positions using OCR
    ocr_data = extract_text_and_positions_from_image(image)

    # Get the width and height of the image for proper scaling
    image_width, image_height = image.size
    overlay = BytesIO()
    canvas = Canvas(overlay, pagesize=(image_width, image_height))

    line_number = 0
    previous_y = None
    line_height = 15  # Approximate line height (adjust for spacing)

    non_empty_lines = []  # Store non-empty line y-coordinates

    # Collect non-empty lines based on OCR bounding boxes
    for i in range(len(ocr_data['level'])):
        y = int(ocr_data['top'][i])
        text = ocr_data['text'][i]

        # Skip empty or invalid text
        if not text.strip():
            continue

        # Track non-empty lines based on their Y positions
        if previous_y is None or abs(previous_y - y) >= line_height:
            non_empty_lines.append(y)
            previous_y = y

    # Sort the y-positions to ensure numbering from top to bottom
    non_empty_lines.sort(reverse=True)

    # Draw line numbers starting from the 10th non-empty line
    for i, y in enumerate(non_empty_lines):
        # Start numbering from the 10th line and continue numbering every 10th line
        if i >= 9 and (i + 1) % 10 == 0:
            line_number += 10
            canvas.setFont("Helvetica", 30)
            # Align the line number on the right side of the page
            canvas.drawString(image_width - 70, y, str(line_number))  # Adjust `image_width - 50` to align right

    # Add page number in the top-right corner
    canvas.setFont("Helvetica", 80)
    canvas.drawString(image_width - 70, image_height - 60, str(page_num + 1))  # Page number
    canvas.save()
    overlay.seek(0)

    # Convert PIL image to a PDF format
    img_pdf = BytesIO()
    image.save(img_pdf, format='PDF')
    img_pdf.seek(0)

    # Create a PdfReader object for both the image and the overlay
    image_reader = PdfReader(img_pdf)
    overlay_pdf = PdfReader(overlay)

    # Get the first page from both
    page = image_reader.pages[0]
    page.merge_page(overlay_pdf.pages[0])  # Merge the overlay with the image page

    pdf_writer.add_page(page)

# Save the final PDF with line numbers
with open(output_pdf_path, 'wb') as output_file:
    pdf_writer.write(output_file)

print(f"Line numbers added to scanned PDF and saved as {output_pdf_path}.")


    # Example usage
    input_pdf = r'C:\PyCharm 
Projects\AirRumi\media\20240703125513952.pdf'  # Path to the scanned PDF
 output_pdf = r'C:\PyCharm 
Projects\AirRumi\media\text_with_line_numbers.pdf'  # Output PDF

# For scanned PDFs
 add_line_numbers_to_scanned_pdf(input_pdf, output_pdf)

This is the updated code, the output is not well aligned with the text

Issue is that the system will be allowing all range of scanned PDFs including handwritten, the cleaning up will be very challenging.

What have you tried so far? The code you gave is just for PDFs with text layers and if I remember correctly, I already pointed you to Tesseract and its hOCR output for example. Just convert image-based pages to image files (using pdf2image or pdfimages for example or extract the images using pypdf) and then use pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(image, extension='hocr') to get the desired data. ocr_line classes elements wrap each line and provide a bounding box you can use for positioning.

I have updated the current code I have and what the output am getting, Kindly assist

Am not to see the comments, assist

Guys no progress yet
